# Не обновляется количество дней в феврале при изменении года на високосный

Tags: java, android

Вот код, месяца обновляются отлично, а вот с високосностью какая то беда:

```
package game.life.ru.basicviews;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public NumberPicker yearChoose = null ;
    public NumberPicker monthChoose = null ;
    public int maxDay = 31;
    public int maxYear = 2216;
    public int minYear = 1940;
    public int maxMonth = 12;
    public int minMonth = 1;
    public int minDay = 1;
    public int yearChoseInt;
    public int monthChoseInt = 0;
    public int modif = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NumberPicker numberPicker3 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);
        numberPicker3.setMaxValue(maxYear);
        numberPicker3.setMinValue(minYear);
        numberPicker3.setValue(1990);
        yearChoseInt = numberPicker3.getValue();//получаем значение года

        NumberPicker numberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
        numberPicker2.setMaxValue(maxMonth);
        numberPicker2.setMinValue(minMonth);
        numberPicker2.setValue(1);

        NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(minDay);
        numberPicker.setValue(1);



        yearChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);//проверяем изменение года
        yearChoose.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener(){//перегрузка после изменения значения года
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker3,int minYear, int yearChoseInt){
                if(yearChoseInt%4==0 && yearChoseInt%100 !=0 || yearChoseInt%400==0){   //проверка высокосности года
                    modif = 1;
                }
                else {
                    modif = 0;
                }

                NumberPicker numberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);

                monthChoseInt = numberPicker2.getValue();//получаем значение месяца
                monthChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);//проверяем что за значение введено
                monthChoose.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {//проверка на изменение значения и запуск перегрузки
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker2,int minMonth, int monthChoseInt) {

                    switch (monthChoseInt)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        case 3:
                        case 5:
                        case 7:
                        case 8:
                        case 10:
                        case 12:
                            maxDay = 31;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                        case 6:
                        case 9:
                        case 11:
                            maxDay = 30;
                            break;
                        default:
                            maxDay = 28 + modif;
                    }
                    NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
                    numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);
                    numberPicker.setMinValue(minDay);
                }
        });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно пнуть событие смены месяца внутри события смены года -  после вызова `monthChoose.setOnValueChangedListener`, или поместить логику `... numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);` в отдельный метод и вызывать его в обоих местах.

Comment: Может лучше воспользоваться стандартным DatePicker?

Answer (score 1):

Если вынести метод изменения месяца отдельно и вызывать его при изменении и года и месяца, то будет что-то вроде того:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public NumberPicker yearChoose = null ;
    public NumberPicker monthChoose = null ;
    public int maxDay = 31;
    public int maxYear = 2216;
    public int minYear = 1940;
    public int maxMonth = 12;
    public int minMonth = 1;
    public int minDay = 1;
    public int yearChoseInt;
    public int monthChoseInt = 0;
    public int modif = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NumberPicker numberPicker3 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);
        numberPicker3.setMaxValue(maxYear);
        numberPicker3.setMinValue(minYear);
        numberPicker3.setValue(1990);
        yearChoseInt = numberPicker3.getValue();//получаем значение года

        NumberPicker numberPicker2 = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
        numberPicker2.setMaxValue(maxMonth);
        numberPicker2.setMinValue(minMonth);
        numberPicker2.setValue(1);

        NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(minDay);
        numberPicker.setValue(1);



        yearChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker3);//проверяем изменение года
        yearChoose.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener(){//перегрузка после изменения значения года
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker3,int minYear, int yearChoseInt){
                 if(yearChoseInt%4==0 && yearChoseInt%100 !=0 || yearChoseInt%400==0){   //проверка высокосности года
                    modif = 1;
                }
                else {
                    modif = 0;
                }
                changeData(monthChoseInt);

            }
        });

        monthChoseInt = numberPicker2.getValue();//получаем значение месяца
        monthChoose = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);//проверяем что за значение введено
        monthChoose.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {//проверка на изменение значения и запуск перегрузки
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker2,int minMonth, int monthChoseInt) {
                changeData(monthChoseInt);
            }
        });

    }

    private void changeData(int monthChoose){
        monthChoseInt = monthChoose;
        switch (monthChoose)
        {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                maxDay = 31;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                maxDay = 30;
                break;
            default:
                maxDay = 28 + modif;
        }
        NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(maxDay);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(minDay);
    }


}
```